# Disable GMail signature two dashes '--' using GMail API

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to create a PHP application which will set a user's email signature up automatically. This part works, and I'm able to set signatures for users.

My problem is that I cannot find any option on the SendAs setting which will disable the two dashes inserted before the signature in GMail.

You can disable this option manually in GMail by unticking the box labeled 'Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it'

but there doesn't seem to be any such option in the [SendAs resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs)

Any advice?

Comment: I'm curious too. I suspect the config setting is not part of the SendAs resource but as part of something higher in the tree

Comment: @spkvn did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Badal sorry, no.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no Gmail API for

> Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the
>   "--"

option. We hope that Gmail team will take care of our needs :) .